# Android Application Force Closes after Screen Rotation and Notification (Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, notifications

So my application has a fragment with a built in runnable timer, that will create a notification on the device once the time reaches 0. However, after a screen orientation, the app force closes and logcat produces 
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"

Here's the full logcat:

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4160)
        at com.example.android.courtcounter.tabs.TimerFragment.createNotification(TimerFragment.java:178)
        at com.example.android.courtcounter.tabs.TimerFragment$1.run(TimerFragment.java:52)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

the error happens here:

```
           //Creates the notification from the Main Activity class
public void createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Score Counter and Timer")
                    .setContentText("Time's up!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), TimerFragment.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity());
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    int mID = 001;
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(mID,mBuilder.build());
}
```

Apparently notifying after orientation change will cause it to have the "attempt to invoke method on a null object reference" issue.

Here's where I call the notification method i created:

```
    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (timeLeft > 501) {
            timerTextViewSetUp();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            timeLeft = timeLeft - 500;
            //Log.v(TimerFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "The timer has been set");
        } else if (timeLeft<501 && timeLeft>0) {
            timeLeft = 0;
            timerTextView.setText("0:00");
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            vibrate();
            createNotification();
            setPauseButtonToStartButton();
        }
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but here's my onSavedInstanceState code:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Save state information
    savedInstanceState.putLong(TIME_LEFT_KEY, timeLeft);

}
```

and this is in onCreateView:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        timeLeft = savedInstanceState.getLong(TIME_LEFT_KEY);
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        //Log.v(TimerFragment.class.getSimpleName(), Long.toString(timeLeft));
    }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orientation changes cause activity to be recreated. Use  [removeCallbacks(Runnable r)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to remove the runnable so it doesn't get called after the old activity is destroyed. You can recreate the runnable and handler once new activity is created.